# Request made to URL containing pieces of code

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, iis-7

I found in the error logs of my website requests made to URLs containing invalid characters. The URLs that are requested are made of pieces of code, e.g:

```
/Templat<div class="right-se
```

*The URLs are always a mix of pieces of code. Different parts from different places in the same page. Liket the example above, which the first part is a path to the CSS file and the second is a HTML tag.

I have been analyzing all the errors found to try to find a pattern, but no luck. They happen in different pages, of different types.

The only two pattern I seem to find is that all the URLs or most of the start with `'/Templates'` or a piece of that text `'/T'` and that all the errors are in IE7 and IE8

This is the error shown in the logs:

```
Class and function: Global.asax.Application_Error
Exception type: 
Message: RawUrl: /T        <div id=
Referrer path and query: /aboutus
User web browser: IE. Version: 8.0.

A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (<).
Stack trace:    at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context)
```

I have not been able to reproduce the error in the test environment or production, and don't know really where to start looking at my code.

The website is made in ASP .NET running in IIS7 with .NET 4.0

Thanks

Comment: You might want to look at any links that are generated that may have a misplaced quotation mark symbol. It looks like html is being injected into a link somewhere, and often improper quote matching is a culprit.

Comment: I agree there is some link generated wrong, with some HTML injected but it does not happen in the same page and not all the time. The site has a lot of traffic and it happens 3-4 times on normal traffic hours. I have not found the circumstances or conditions that make this bad links to be generated. Actually I am not sure it the problem is triggered by the user clicking on a broken link or a background process posting to a bad link. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP .Net does a [request validation](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/request-validation) for preventing different "hacking" attacks. When an input looks like that, it raises these errors. 

Many crawlers scan websites, some might be asked to do this (your company paid for) other simply to find vulnerabilities and exploit them. The requested URLs might not look with something you have in the sitemap.

Comment: I know about this robots scanning websites. From time to time we can see attempts to weird URLs, probably robots or hack attack. But this last ones we have found are constant (3-4 per hour and 10-15 during rush hours) and all of the URLs requested are pieces of the source code (path to CSS or JS file mixed with html tags or content of my website, etc). Most of this ones contain a '>', '>', etc and as you mention they are prevented by ASP .NET

Comment: If you can install Elmah, you can track much more info about these errors than what is in EventViewer. Info like referrer, posted values if any, cookies, more server variables etc. Also you might check the IPs and block if it is the case

Comment: I installed Elmah, really nice tool, unfortunately the logs didn't show anything related with the root of the problem After reading it seems that the page, after loaded by the client is missing some kbs in the header section (could happen at other sections, but if they don't trigger some kind of exception or error, is hard to tell), therefore the client tries to download a css/script file with a corrupted path.

Comment: I found an article that talks about this bug (The 4kb bug" but it says it has been fixed and exclusively of IE8, but my logs show the same error in IE7, IE8, IE9 (no FF, Chrome or Safari). The question is if this is the same problem that was supposedly fixed or is a different issue with similar symptoms?

Comment: /Templat<div class="right-se this is a piece of html in the end. Can you validate the html from your page? http://validator.w3.org/ And check if it has any errors?

Comment: My page has valid markup, I just get the BOM warning "Byte-Order Mark found in UTF-8 File." The errors in the logs appear on different pages all the time, it is not consistent at all. The only consistent part is that they all happen in IE. The website gets thousands of visits each day and I just get around 3 errors per hour. The problem is that I don't know the scenario/circumstances that trigger this problem.

Comment: is the referrer of the requests one of your pages?

Comment: Yes, it is one of my pages. Reading a bit more about the issue found some cases where the problem was the text-encoding, I will try to do some tests and see if I can get rid of the problem, but besides this theory have no idea what else can it be.